# Cataclysm substitute to gear/player score?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

In Wrath of the Lich King there were some nice add-ons I liked that showed your player score (based on your items) and also other player's score. In Cataclysm I don't seem to find anything that resembles that. Is there a feature or an addon that shows some kind of player score in Cataclysm?

I usually use it to create fast dungeon/raids party.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GearScore still exists (In fact, it still uses the same Curse page). It is new, improved, and a larger memory hog. It is now called [PlayerScore](http://www.curse.com/addons/wow/gearscore). From experience on my server though, it isn't used very much anymore. This isn't an in-game tool, but I use [WoW-Heroes](http://www.wow-heroes.com) to check gear, gems, and enchantments for pug members in my Gold dkp runs.

Answer (score 1):

In Cataclysm a Gearscore is implemented in the game. You can see it in your character view by pressing "C" und then click on one of the buttons in the upper right corner (i dont remember the caption exactly). this is your offical gearscore which will be used to grant you access to the dungeons and raids..

yesterday we couldn't join a dungeon cause of the gearscore of one guildmate. the addon "PlayerScore" showed a gearscore which should have been high enough to get access to the dungeon but we couldn't enter. after deactivating the addon the ingame gearscore was much lower!

so i do NOT recommend an addon for gearscore!

(sorry for my english.. i'm not a native speaker)

Comment: that wasn't gearscore why you couldn't enter an instance, it was itemlevel, it's current equivalent and effectively an weighted average of the item levels of each individual item. The old gearscore was calculated different, and can still be seen on websites like wowhead and elsewhere (though the wowhead profiler is offline as of right now). Itemlevel is displayed on your character screen, and if you can't enter an instance the dungeon finder will tell you who in the party has their levels too low.

Answer (score 1):

The current equivalent is item level. It is shown in the character screen ("C" by default) in the right hand pane when you expand it. 
The level for each item is also shown in the item information for that item. A specific minimum item level is needed to enter Cataclysm instances.
It's not without its problems as item levels can be misleading at times, especially as pvp items tend to have a higher item level than do pve items with similar stats, enabling people to enter instances for which they are actually undergeared. 
It's also massively abused by some people to prevent anyone not in their clique from joining their raids or other groups (by demanding unrealistically high minimum item levels, essentially item levels that can only be obtained by those who've been running those instances for a long time and already have collected all the gear that can be obtained there). This idiocy has now reached the stage where demands for pugs to join Lich King raids often include having an item level that requires having cleared Dragon Soul on normal mode several times.